# Hide the span with a class name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am stuck on what to do when hiding a span that has a certain class name.  I can't use `this` because it refers to the input.  Here is my script:

```
//uncheck all checkboxes
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);

$("input[type=checkbox]").each( function (index) {
    $(this).addClass("doc" + index);
})

$("input").change( function () {

    var docName = $(this).parent().find("span");
    var className = $(this).attr("class");

if(this.checked) {

        $("span.noneAttached").fadeOut('slow', function () {

            docName.clone().appendTo(".attachedDocuments").addClass(className).after("<br />").text();

        });
    }

else if (!this.checked && ($(".attachedDocuments > span").hasClass(className))) {


    //hide the span with the class name

}

});
```

The `else if` checks to see if a checkbox is not checked and if the parent div contains any children with the class name.  If so, hide it.

Where do I go from here?  I am sure this answer is obvious, but I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Concatenate the class name to the selector like this

```
$("span."+className).hide();
```

Comment: Duh.  Good one.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".attachedDocuments span." + classname).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.classname').hide();
$('.' + classnameasvariable).hide()
```